# How to upgrade ember cli version

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I upgraded ember-cli to version 2.4.3

```
npm install -g ember-cli
```

I can see -- ember-cli@2.4.3 , in the listed dependencies, 
but when I check :

```
(master *)$ ember -v
version: 2.4.2
node: 5.6.0
os: darwin x64
```

ember cli version is still 2.4.2

what's wrong ?

Answer (score 11):

Updating Ember-CLI's version and ember project's version are different thing.

To update Ember-CLI:

```
npm uninstall -g ember-cli 
npm cache clean 
bower cache clean 
npm install -g ember-cli@1.13.14
```

To update your project:

```
rm -rf node_modules bower_components dist tmp 
npm install --save-dev ember-cli@1.13.14 
npm install 
bower install
ember init
```

**Here is the resource**: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases

I strongly recomend you to select which files will be overwritten. You should compare diffs of files. application.hbs, router.js, environment.js, ember-cli-build.js are important files those you don't want them to be overwritten.

---

**UPDATE 2020-02-19:**

[ember-cli-update](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-update)
handles updating your project.

Comment: Hi do we want to upgrade our project after upgrading ember-cli version

Comment: I'd prefer that way.

Comment: To update your project theres a package https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-update which handles that well. It doesnt help with upgrading the version on your machine though.