# How to upgrade ember-cli globally to run `ember new` the latest

Tags: npm, ember.js

I'm trying to get Ember-cli globally to the latest version so that when I run `ember new` it actually installs the latest version. I've followed the instructions here: https://cli.emberjs.com/release/basic-use/upgrading/

```
npm uninstall -g ember-cli
npm install -g ember-cli
ember --version
```

And the version (v2.15) does not reflect the change (v3.7). I've also checked the version just after uninstalling and it still shows up as if it hadn't been removed. I've also tried running `npm cache clean` after the uninstall.

I'm running ubuntu 16.04

I've also tried following the similar question here: [How to upgrade ember cli version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330202/how-to-upgrade-ember-cli-version) and it does NOT solve my problem.

Is there some way to select what version to use when running ember new? Or change the global version selected?

Comment: That's weird. Could you try something like `npm install -g ember-cli@3.7`?

Comment: Did you run the ``ember --version `` command inside an ember-cli project folder? Then it will use the projects ember-cli from ``./node_modules``.

Comment: just to piggyback on @Enno, you have to change the `package.json` version of `ember-cli` within your project. This is useful since you can run different projects with different ember cli versions

Comment: You might have installed ember-cli twice, once for current user and once for all users. This may happen when you change npm configuration to not require sudo. Try `which ember` after `npm uninstall -g ember-cli`. I bet it reports you some global path. Since your npm configuration is only installing (and removing) for current user, global `ember-cli` stays the same. It might even overrule installation for your user.

Comment: whats the output of `which ember` and `ls -lisa $(which ember)`?

Comment: @Lux `which ember` /usr/local/bin/ember `ls -lisa $(which ember)` 54401770 0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Aug 23  2016 /usr/local/bin/ember -> ../lib/node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember